# Should I leave if after few months I see a complete lack of direction in the company?

Tags: career-development, careers

I recently started a job at a new data-analysis company because I wanted to gain experience in a related but different area after more than 3 years at my previous company as a software developer. I am still junior and would like to experiment with different technologies and gain new skills before settling on some area.

Now, the company I joined turned out to have some problems, and was reorganized just after I started here, a process that involved laying off a consistent part of the staff. I also digged into the previous history of the company and it seems that the company lacks a competent management that can fix a strategy. Basically, people have been working sloppily just to get projects delivered but there is no long term plan on how to increase our productivity and good collaboration between different groups.

Obviously, the current situation looks confused and will take quite some time to be clarified. The reorganization might open some interesting opportunities, but it's very early to say it with certainty. My role in the company is not directly related to delivering data-analysis but rather on the required infrastructure/tools.

I am demotivated and unproductive right now. The uncertainty caused by the reorg is not going away anytime soon and I am worried that the culture of the place will not change.

Since I started recently, should I search for a more stable place/better opportunities or should I keep working there and hope that in the next year things will improve and opportunities will open up? On one side I know I should give some time for the thing to be worked out and I fear that I just have unrealistic expectations, on the other side I am very worried that I am not going anywhere in this place.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brush up your CV and take a look what's out there.

Leaving after a year and stating the reasons above could potentially bring up the question:

> "Why did you stay there for so long if you didn't see any direction in the company?"

Companies usually have 3 month probation periods both for the company itself but also the employee to ensure they are a good fit for one another. You've already shown you can stick with a company for 3 years and now you have experience of a workplace which doesn't work for you so you know some good post interview questions to ask.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I leave if after few months I see a complete lack of direction in the company?

Unless you're in a position of authority with all the information, normally you leave if you find a better job or there is a problem with your pay. Not because of vague ideas that things are messy.

> Basically, people have been working sloppily just to get projects delivered but there is no long term plan on how to increase our productivity and good collaboration between different groups.

Many successful, long standing businesses use this model, it's actually the norm in some locales who have a relatively captive customer base.

> I am demotivated and unproductive right now.

Given the environment described it seems unlikely that anyone is going to hold your hand and give you a consoling hug, so you may want to apply for other work before people notice you're not doing anything and terminate your employment.